# midleware message system c++

Tags: c++, unix, messaging

I have low layer system like ACE. and thinking about message sending system between tasks, which include marsh/demarsh message .. may be xml based.. like SOAP or ORB is, but they to old I think..
and have no time write it under boost.spirit parsers/generators or something like this.
Is anybody know good c++ cross-platform libraries.. xmllib, something else?

Comment: Grammar and spelling _are_ important!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Names that come to mind

*Note - draft editing for links and checks*

- protobuf (google)
- Boost MPI
- CORBA/IIOP:

  - Orbit2 [http://projects.gnome.org/ORBit2/] (also with pyOrb)
  - omniORB
  - TAO (http://www.theaceorb.com/)
  - CORBIX
  - bonobo (Gnome, might have been replaced with one of the previous by now)
- Don't forget .NET remoting (fully supported by Mono)

perhaps relevant

- [libtscb](http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/libtscb/) - more in the field of event handling and concurrency IIRC

---

see also [Drop-in replacement for MICO Corba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038405/drop-in-replacement-for-mico-corba/7628581#7628581)

Comment: There's also [DBus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus) which is IMHO one of most popular *nix IPCs.